# Items not being saved to localStorage

Tags: angular

It would appear that the onSubmit function below is saving to localStorage but I deployed the code to the Web and when I refreshed the page, the shopping cart got emptied. I can't test the code after every modification because I'm in development mode and the page re-compiles when it's refreshed but I can test it with the deleteItem function which uses splice. Splice only works on an array and when I click the delete button, the product gets cleared so that tells me it's not using localStorage.

In the component:

```js
items = [];

public onSubmit(thumbnail, quantity, product_name, product_price){
    const data = {
        thumbnail,
        quantity,
        product_name,
        product_price
    };
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.items.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')));
    this.isSubmitted = true;
}

deleteItem(i){
    this.items.splice(i, 1);
}
```

In the HTML:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <td>
        <button type="button" (click)="deleteItem(i)">X</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="{{item.thumbnail}}" />
    </td>
    <td>{{item.quantity}} </td>
    <td>{{item.product_name }} </td>
    <td>{{item.product_price }} </td>
    <td>{{item.quantity * item.product_price  }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('items')` only ever has one object in it, since that's all you set it to. Set it to `JSON.stringify(this.items)` if you want the whole array of items.

Comment: Thanks, Heretic Monkey but when I use your suggestion,
the following line of code updates the cart with an empty array:
this.items.push(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('this.items')));

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to think about how to restructure your code now that you're saving the entire array of items in storage. For instance, maybe it makes sense to push `data` into `this.items`, then set storage to the serialized array? You'll also need to think about initializing `this.items` to what you get out of storage when you first load the component.

Comment: Thanks, Heretic Monkey, but I don't have a clue.

Comment: @MaureenMoore is this correct java script object initialization ? I think it look like the following way  var product = { "product_name" : "IPhone SE"}

Answer (score 0):

Just changed structure of the product object and it is working.

```
items = [];  

var product = {  
thumbnail : "IPhone SE",  
quantity: "2",  
product_name: "iphone",  
product_price: "45k"  
}; 

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(product));

this.items.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')));
```

**OutPut :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, RajeeshMenoth, but the product still gets deleted when I use splice and that tells me it's an array and not in localStorage.

Comment: @MaureenMoore Once you delete all the information from an items array using splice method then it should be empty. If you wan't to revert back already submitted items value then use 'this.items.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')));' and it will help you to refill the localStorage value into items array.